# Need to access a serial port from different classes

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am using a serial port object that was generated by the designer in C# (non static).

I need to be able to access it from methods that are static in different classes (I know it is a bad practice but that is what I inherit)

The port access use the below code.

```
    public bool Read_Board_Port()
    {
        byte[] bData = new byte[256];
        string message;
        bool sucess = false;
        try
        {
            if (!(serialBoardPort.IsOpen == true))
                Connect_To_Board(Globals.BoardportName, Globals.BoardbaudRate, Globals.Boardparity, Globals.BoardstopBits, Globals.BoarddataBits);

           if(CMDDirect || Globals.HostCommandString)
            {
                serialBoardPort.ReadTimeout = 1000; // Timeout if no answer from the port.
                message = serialBoardPort.ReadLine();
                Globals.RXBoardBuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                Write_To_Console_Dr(message);
                sucess = true;
            }
           else
            {
                serialBoardPort.Read(Globals.RXBoardBuff, 0, Constants.RXBOARDBUFFSIZE);
                if (Check_Command_Correct(Globals.RXBoardBuff, Globals.CommandOut))
                    sucess = true;
                else
                {
                    Write_Error_To_Console_Dr(Constants.ERRORDATAFROMBOARDPORT);
                    sucess = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Constants.ERRORNODATABOARPORT);
            sucess = false;
        }

        return sucess;
    }
```

If I declare ***new*** a different instance of the serial port will be used, I need to use the port that is already open.

Thanks

Comment: If you really have to use the static methods, just add a parameter to the static method containing the Serial Port Object.  I would recommend using a non-static approach though.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure I fully understand your suggestion. The port was generated with VS designer, how can I add the Serial Port Object and where?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Matthew Spencer you should pass the serial port as a parameter to the static methods that needs it. First create a method on your board class or whatever its name is that returns the instance of your serial port. Then use it to get the serial port for use to the static methods you mentioned.

Something like this should be what you need..

```
public bool Read_Board_Port()
    {
        byte[] bData = new byte[256];
        string message;
        bool sucess = false;
        try
        {
            if (!(serialBoardPort.IsOpen == true))
                Connect_To_Board(Globals.BoardportName, Globals.BoardbaudRate, Globals.Boardparity, Globals.BoardstopBits, Globals.BoarddataBits);

           if(CMDDirect || Globals.HostCommandString)
            {
                serialBoardPort.ReadTimeout = 1000; // Timeout if no answer from the port.
                message = serialBoardPort.ReadLine();
                Globals.RXBoardBuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                Write_To_Console_Dr(message);
                sucess = true;
            }
           else
            {
                serialBoardPort.Read(Globals.RXBoardBuff, 0, Constants.RXBOARDBUFFSIZE);
                if (Check_Command_Correct(Globals.RXBoardBuff, Globals.CommandOut))
                    sucess = true;
                else
                {
                    Write_Error_To_Console_Dr(Constants.ERRORDATAFROMBOARDPORT);
                    sucess = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Constants.ERRORNODATABOARPORT);
            sucess = false;
        }

        return sucess;
    }

// since serialBoardPort seems to be a globally declared variable
public SerialPort GetInstance()
{
    return serialBoardPort;
}

// Let's name your class as board..
// on somewhere in your app code:

Board board = // GetValue 
SerialPort boardSerialPort = board.GetInstance();

ClassXXX.StaticMethodNeedsPort(boardSerialPort); // pass your serial port to the static method
```

UPDATE: Since there was a bit of misunderstanding as the questioner said..

I suggest using an IoC container, read more [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/568157/Dependency-Inversion-Principle-IoC-Container-and-D)

Here is what I use. Normally this is already a part of frameworks such as [MVVM Cross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross).

CODE:

```
public class Core
{
    private static readonly Core instance = new Core();

    private Dictionary<Type, object> container;

    private Core()
    {
        container = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    public void RegisterSingleton<T>(T value) where T : class
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        if (!container.ContainsKey(type))
            container.Add(type, value);
    }

    public T GetSingleton<T>() where T : class
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        if (container.ContainsKey(type))
            return (T)container[type];
        else
            throw new Exception("Singleton instance not registered.");
    }

    public void RemoveSingleton<T>() where T : class
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        if (container.ContainsKey(type))
            container.Remove(type);
    }

    public void ClearSingletons()
    {
        container.Clear();
    }

    public static Core Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }
}
```

When your application loads add this line:

```
Core.Instance.ClearSingletons();
```

In case it already has a port upon loading since it is auto-generated by C# just register the instance too..

```
Core.Instance.RegisterSingleton(MySerialPortObject); // Or class. Can be object
```

On the part of the application when you need the port just get its instance like this...

```
SerialPort _myPort = Core.Instance.GetSingleton<X>(); // Where X value is the type of your registered object. If you are registering a SerialPort then replace X with SerialPort.
```

You can get the instance of your port anywhere you like. When I use this I normally register implementation of interfaces so that I can get it like

```
IFileHandler _fileHandler = Core.Instance.GetSingleton<IFileHandler>() // Where I registered the class that implements IFileHandler upon the startup of my application
```

Sorry for the long answer.

Comment: Just a place holder. Whether you initialize your board class or get its value from a certain function. Up to you.

Comment: Thanks John, I am not sure I fully understand.I added to my main class FormMain the code: public SerialPort GetInstance()
        {
            return serialBoardPort;
        } after that I created a class     class BoardPort
    {
        BoardPort board = Globals.BoardportName;
        SerialPort boardSerialPort = BoardPort.GetInstance();
    }, I am not sure that was your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: No. I just named the class of your sample code as board. Just add the public SerialPort GetInstance() { return serialBoardPort; } to that class. well in your case it was FormMain.cs; The main point of this code is to have a public method that returns the instance of the serialBoardPort which is as you said will be used to methods that are static in different classes (These methods should accept SerialPort as parameter). The small code I added on my answer is just to show how you can use the instance as parameter to some static method...

Comment: Thanks John, I think there is a bit of confusion, the method I am in is static and the method I need to read the port is not, see the code above. Thanks

Comment: @Sharon I see. I updated my answer and see if it is what you need.

Comment: John, I am still having an issue, would you be interested in 1-2 hours of consulting to help me on this?

Comment: @Sharon sure I'll help you out. What's the issue?

Comment: in the static method I did:  FormMain fri = new FormMain();
                    SerialPort _myPort = Core.Instance.GetSingleton<SerialPort>(); 
                    fri.Get_Samples_String(_myPort); Then inside the Get Sample method I did  public void Get_Samples_String(SerialPort BoardPort) ttt = BoardPort.ReadLine(); I got an exception saying the ort is not open, I also tried as follow and got the same exception SerialPort tmpPort = Core.Instance.GetSingleton<SerialPort>();
            ttt = tmpPort.ReadLine(); I was registering the singleton as you suggested. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @Sharon Did you properly registered the SerialPort singleton with the generated one? If yes, then you have the same instance of the SerialPort now the error you're facing is thatsomewhere in your code the instance of the SerialPort was closed before you tried to use it. So in order to read data from it you have to open it first. Inside your GetSampleString you have to add a serialPort.Open() before trying to read from it, otherwise, find the piece of code that's closing the port and remove it...

Comment: @Joe, I am not sure it is getting closed. If I am trying to reopen it it will not let me since the physical port is already open. When debugging and looking into _myPort looks is it is pointing to the correct port (at least from the port name). Looks as the singelton object don't point to the same physical port. Do you have an email, I would like to discuss with you the consultant.

Comment: Since it is pointing to the correct PortName then it is working as it should because the SerialPort object relies on the PortName to identify which physical port to use. I find it weird about you're getting an exception saying the port is not open but when you try to it then say it is. Contact me through thebluepurple19@gmail.com

Comment: It is not saying it is open. I am checking if it is open, since it is not I am trying to open it but getting an error message saying it cant open the port. My assumption is that the physical port is already assign (not the driver), that why it will not let me open again the physical port.

Comment: A serial port can only be opened by 1 at a time. Two threads can't access the same port at the same time. This must be the reason why you can't use it in your other class. You must wait for the first process to close it then on the next process you should open it again. Some uses locks to work around this to make it thread safe. I am just not sure what you want to achieve.